# How to change the mouse pointer colour?

Tags: themes, mouse, colors

I am using the ample theme and I quite like it, but I can't see the mouser pointer when moving over emacs and emacs is activated; as the emacs background and the mouse pointer are black, I would like to have the mouse pointer in e.g. red.

How can I change the colour of the mouse pointer?

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1343.14) of 2014-10-27 on Rainers-MBP-4
```

OS X Yosemite

Comment: I am sure I can, as the colour of the cursor changes when I move over emacs, and the colour depends on the colour theme I have chosen - my OS is OS X Yosemite by the way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just found [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PointerShape), did not tried it:

```
(set-mouse-color "red")
```

Comment: Perfect - works perfectly.

Comment: Not completely perfect. It only affects the current frame. I haven't figured out how to set the default for all frames yet.

Comment: @tbc0 Just add a line in `init.el` and restart all the emacs processes.

Comment: @tbc0 Or, follow nanny's answer and save it for future sessions and restart the emacs processes

Comment: `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(mouse-color . "white"))` handles it for new frames as well.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want to customize the face:

```
M-x customize-face RET mouse RET
```