# Make Emacs not change mouse pointer color and theme

Tags: colors, mouse-pointer

I found the this answer to the question of how to change ones mouse pointer color for when the mouse pointer is hovering over Emacs: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3185/10090

However, this really only seems to work for the current frame and `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(mouse-color . "white"))` does not seem to work for me. What I would really like to do however, is to avoid changing the mouse pointer at all, when it moves to Emacs.

Is there a way to not make Emacs change the pointer color/theme at all?

Additional info:

- GNU Emacs 28.2

**EDIT:**

Mouse pointer color refers to literally the color of the mouse pointer. The terminology comes from https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PointerShape.

Comment: *"change the pointer color/theme"* isn't clear - what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear to me. Please show exactly what you tried, step by step, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file). Say what you expect/want to happen at each step, and what happens there instead.

Adding `(mouse-color . "white")` does (should), affect all future frames for which nothing different is imposed. Try it. If it doesn't then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. But be aware that some platforms don't let Emacs change the mouse color at all.

Again, that's for future frames *by default*. If you start using themes that impose a different mouse color then, well, `default-frame-alist` can't (and shouldn't) do anything about that.

If you're asking how to work around such a change imposed by a theme, that's a different question. For that, look for a theme-specific setting or hook, or ask the theme author.